# How do I prevent layers from rendering in 3d with Mapbox?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Layers are being rendered in 3d, making them difficult to click, and look bad in general.

[image: An example of the bad rendering - dots following a railroad path are rendered ~500ft in the air]

As you can see in the image, the dots are rendered about 500 ft off the ground. I'm not aware of any configuration changes I made to enable this, and I can't figure out how to prevent it from happening, although it only seems to happen to some layers (as you can see in the screenshot)

I've tried reordering the layers in Mapbox Studio, but I don't know what else I would change, as this seems to happen regardless of any js changes.

Comment: What kind of layers are you creating? Where is the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this was an issue with react-map-gl not being able to render 3d styles correctly. Setting the map to "2d" in Mapbox Studio and using a raster source to generate the 3d terrain seems to have fixed the issue.

https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/examples/terrain